# XSLT 2.0 using Identity Template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I would require help on Identity Template Transformation in xslt 2.0, I tried this for few hours now but could not achieve it.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
         <MsgId>16</MsgId>
      </GrpHdr>
      <PmtInf>
         <PmtInfId>161</PmtInfId>
         <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
         <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
         <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
         <CtrlSum>0.01</CtrlSum>
         <ChrgBr>SL</ChrgBr>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>EFT</InstrId>
            </PmtId>
            <Purp>
               <Prtry>DEP</Prtry>
            </Purp>
            <RmtInf>
               <Strd>
                  <RfrdDocInf>
                     <Tp>
                        <CdOrPrtry>
                           <Cd>SOAC</Cd>
                        </CdOrPrtry>
                     </Tp>
                     <Nb>643525145</Nb>
                     <RltdDt>2018-01-01-07:00</RltdDt>
                  </RfrdDocInf>
                  <RfrdDocAmt>
                     <DuePyblAmt Ccy="EUR">0.01</DuePyblAmt>
                     <RmtdAmt Ccy="EUR">0.01</RmtdAmt>
                  </RfrdDocAmt>
                  <CdtrRefInf>
                     <Ref>643525145</Ref>
                  </CdtrRefInf>
               </Strd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <GrpHdr>
         <MsgId>16</MsgId>
      </GrpHdr>
      <PmtInf>
         <PmtInfId>161</PmtInfId>
         <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
         <BtchBookg>false</BtchBookg>
         <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
         <CtrlSum>0.01</CtrlSum>
         <ChrgBr>SL</ChrgBr>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <PmtId>
               <InstrId>EFT</InstrId>
            </PmtId>
            <Purp>
               <Prtry>DEP</Prtry>
            </Purp>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>643525145</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

If xpath **/Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb** and **/Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf/Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref** are same, then I would need the output as mentioned above. If they are not same, then xslt must return the input data as-is without changes.

I tried this xslt code so far but did not work.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:template match='@* | node()'>
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
            </xsl:copy>
        <!--/xsl:if-->
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf'> 
<xsl:if test="Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb=Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Ustrd>
                <xsl:value-of select="Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref"/>
        </Ustrd>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please could someone help me out to achieve the result, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a default namespace in your XSLT, but this only applies to the unprefixed elements you are creating in your XSLT (i.e the `<Ustrd>` tag), but it doesn't apply to your xpath expressions in your template match. This means your template is not matching any elements, and so isn't getting used.

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can solve this simply by adding `xpath-default-namespace` to your XSLT so that any unprefixed elements in your xpath expressions will treated as in that namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">

<xsl:template match='@* | node()'>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf'> 
<xsl:if test="Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb=Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Ustrd>
                <xsl:value-of select="Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref"/>
        </Ustrd>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, glad to know that I was quite close to achieve the result :) And I replaced if with choose/when and added otherwise condition to get the full desired result.   <xsl:template match='Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/CdtTrfTxInf/RmtInf'> 
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="Strd/RfrdDocInf/Nb=Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref">
  <xsl:copy>
        <Ustrd>
                <xsl:value-of select="Strd/CdtrRefInf/Ref"/>
        </Ustrd>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
  </xsl:copy>   
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>